# Ajax call from BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to call from backbone action from mvc controller which returns a string. I need to be able to use that string later on in javascript.Regarding calling action from controller.I just need similar functionality to this from jquery:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: window.location + "Home/InsertRecord",
            data: {ID : newPersonName},
            success: function(data) {
                // Code after success },
                error: function(){
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax call from backbone.js

```
//Model Declaration
var mod = Backbone. Model. extends ({});
var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Model
});

//Create Collection Object
newCollection = new collection();

//Make Ajax Call
Backbone.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "http://example.com", //Replace your URL here
    data: "", //add your data
    success: function(response){
        //code after success
    }
    error: function () {
        // Code After Erroe
    }

}).complete(function () {
  //Code after complete the request
});
```

For reference check this link 
http://backbonejs.org/#Model